# Помогите найти ошибку. Пытаюсь пройти по всем архивам и достать из них файл "model10.txt"

Tags: python, ос, rar

Сама структура папок выглядит так. Корневая папка - в ней исполняемый файл и папка "all" с пронумерованными по порядку папками, а в них 1 архив с названием results.rar. Из каждого архива нужно вытащить 1 тектовый файл(всегда с 1 названием) и сделать с ним некоторые операции.

```
for address, dirs, files in os.walk('all'):
for name in files:
    rf = RarFile(os.path.join(address, name), "r")
    table = rf.open("model10.txt", mode='r', pwd=None)
    print(table.readline())
```

здесь я циклом пробегаю по папке "all" и в rf записываю архив. Потом мне не удается открыть нужный в нем файл, прикладываю лог из консоли

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:\Documents\work\main.py", line 10, in 
> table = rf.open("model10.txt", mode='r', pwd=None)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 811, in open
> return self._file_parser.open(inf, pwd)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1278, in open
> return self._open_hack(inf, pwd)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1667, in _open_hack
> return self._open_hack_core(inf, pwd, prefix, b"")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1318, in _open_hack_core
> return self._open_unrar(tmpname, inf, pwd, tmpname)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1329, in _open_unrar
> setup = tool_setup()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Bawskre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 3474, in tool_setup
> raise RarCannotExec("Cannot find working tool")
> rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool

Comment: "rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool" - тут скорее библиотека `rarfile.py` не может найти архиватор `rar`, чтобы запустить. Он у вас вообще установлен? В путях он прописан? Вернее, нужен `unrar`, см. ниже.

Comment: "Compressed files are extracted by executing external tool: unrar (preferred), unar, 7zip or bsdtar." https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/